# Why does the upgrade to 20.04 remove Atom?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I am upgrading from 19 to 20 (do-release-upgrade) and it is going to remove Atom, among other things, and I do not want it to. Is there a way to stop that. I realize that I can reinstall it, but the point is that I do not want to. Also I do not understand why it is going to remove it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An upgrade does not remove user installed software only obsolete packages will be deleted (and if needed replaced by their alternatives).

Third-party package sources are disabled during the upgrade though and you need to manually enable them. And there is no way around it: such software can depend on obsolete packages making is impossible to remove those packages without running a greater risk than needed to break your installation.

If you have software installed that is also in the repositories an upgrade will overwrite your software if the current one has a lower version number. But it will not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 *does* remove Atom. I'm not sure, but it seems to be because Ubuntu no longer includes Python 2 (only supporting Python 3). I think Atom should still be able to use the existing packages, but it has to be linked to them. I hope they fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Any packages that have dependencies that get removed by an update or upgrade because they have become obsolete, will also get removed to avoid many issues including conflicts, crashes and broken packages.

Since Atom depends on something that will be removed by the 20.04 upgrade because it has become obsolete, then Atom too, will be removed. This is the reason why you see it as an option to get removed during the upgrade process.

But note that this also happens when you do an upgrade within a specific version. So for example, you do an upgrade in 20.04 after 2 months of not doing any and it tells you it needs to remove X package. This is because either:

- This packages has become obsolete
- Depends on a package that has become obsolete
- Got replaced by something shiny and new
- Depends on a package that got removed because a new version of it came out
- Other reasons.